# Optimize application memory usage

Tags: c++, linux, memory, optimization, memory-leaks

We have a couple of applications, services and libraries written by another teams and third party providers. We need to optimize memory usage for those applications and services. The problem is that we don't have much information about application internals. Of course we have a source codes and rights to modify anything we want, but it's quite difficult to dig into the internals of unknown application.
So the topic is to discuss and share ideas of how to start and what kind of methodologies and tools could we use.

We have valgrind and heaptrack to report memory leaks and overall allocations.
We are considering to use some static code analysis.

I guess there should be people who did something like that already. It would be great to hear what others used for this purposes and what you was able to acheive.

Any useful information on that is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your application is some very exotic case of low latency UDP service that cannot tolerate increased latencies you can easily track your leaks and suboptimal memory allocation with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/).

Start from [Valgrind Memcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) that will help you brush out memory leaks, then continue with [Valgrind Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html), that will help you understand what parts of your program allocate most heap memory.

In case you are indeed a poor person debugging a low latency messaging app you can still do the trick by overriding yourself malloc/realloc/free (example with LD_PRELOAD [here](http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/cpp-heapmap)) and, for instance, aborting the application when it's size grows beyond the certain limit, when the calling stack meets certain criteria. You can even plug [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) and cache/print the top N allocating stacks (like they do in the [heapTracker](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/demo/jvmti/heapTracker/) from the OpenJDK, it's java but the idea is the same).

Comment: Thanks. Actually this was the plan, but I thought there might be another ideas as well.